# How to find the value of "imagepath" from json

Tags: android, json

```
{
    "rank": "-text_relevance",
    "match-expr": "(label 'ifrs')",
    "hits": {
        "found": 14,
        "start": 0,
        "hit": [
            {
                "id": "m9749",
                "data": {
                    "actionurl": [
                        "http://ias-/hjhjk"
                    ],
                    "description": [
                        "IFRS 3 Business Combinations  The objective of the IFRS is to enhance the relevance, reliability and"
                    ],
                    "educator": [
                        " Pvt. Ltd"
                    ],
                    "featured": [
                        "N"
                    ],
                    "imagepath": [
                        "http://WMHCEEHTM/bookstore/14828384_15351162_96526729_P.jpg"
                    ],
                    "rating": [],
                    "text_relevance": [
                        "690"
                    ],
                    "title": [
                        "IAS 27, IFRS 3, IAS 28, IAS 31 Consolidation Part II"
                    ],
                    "topic": [
                        "Accounting",
                        "Banking / Finance / Accounts",
                        "Skill Development & Professional"
                    ],
                    "type": [
                        "MODULE"
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "info": {
        "rid": "6cab70a42101dc6625e2eaea1a18f5b88388923b0fc31965ecd3b9820036dab0b77d928ca7a50a49",
        "time-ms": 4,
        "cpu-time-ms": 4
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you update the question with the methods you have tried? your research on this

Comment: only change the value

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);

JSONObject hits = json.getJSONObject("hits");
JSONArray hit_array = hits.getJSONArray("hit");

for(int i = 0; i < hit_array.lenght(); i++){
       JSONObject obj = hit_array.getJSONObject(i);
       JSONObject data = obj.getJSONObject("data");
       JSONArray imagepath_array = data.getJSONArray("imagepath");

       for(int j = 0; j < imagepath_array.lenght(); j++)
             String imagepath_url = imagepath_array.getString(j);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Guess you are talking about keeping/accessing JSON format in Java. You can achieve that using a library like Gson to parse the response into a JsonArray like so,

```
JsonArray yourObj = new JsonParser()
                          .parse(your_json_string)
                          .getAsJsonObject();
// Access your object like so - yourObj.get("hits").getAsJsonObject().get("hit").getAsJsonArray();
// loop through the array, to get each object, in that object get property
```

Gson Library link - https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Does this help?